# How to copy a string from certain index to an another string in JAVA

Tags: java, string

How to copy a `String` from certain index to an another `String` in `Java`

example : `String s[] = {"0","a","b","c","d","e"};`

Need to copy string `s` from index 1 - rest to an another string `s1` (String s1[])

Kindly, help with this issue

Comment: This is `String` arrays, not `String`s. You can use `System.arraycopy`.

Comment: Could you please explain with a sample code please im new to java

Comment: Just [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+copy+array&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) it. SO is not a tutorials site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Arrays.copyOfRange()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28char[],%20int,%20int%29)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String s[] = {"0","a","b","c","d","e"};
        String s1[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(s, 1,s.length);// copies content from s 1 index to rest
        System.out.println(s1);
    }
```

Comment: @Lingaraj pls accept/upvote the answer if it help you

Answer (score 1):

Use [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)), which is in the SDK to achieve your result.